# POST variable from SELECT into sql query to output to an INPUT

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, function

Using Chain `SELECT` works great from `SELECT` to `SELECT`, I'm trying to do `SELECT` to `INPUT`.

My `mainpage.php`

`<label>Manufacturer</label>
 <select>My Select statement is here</select>
 <label>Model</label>
 <select name="modelname">My Select statement is fed from the select above</select>
 <label>Rating</label>
 <input name="rating"></input>`

This is the `jQuery` I have in the `<head>` section on the `mainpage.php`

```
<script>     
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#modelname").change(function(){
    var id = $("select#modelname option:selected").attr('value');
       $.post("assets/configs/getdata.php", {id:id}, function(data){
           $("input[name='rating']").html(data);
           console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and finally the `getdata.php`

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$modelid = $_POST[id];
$sql = "SELECT EfficiencyRating FROM AllModels WHERE ModelID = '$modelid' ";
$res = odbc_exec($cnn, $sql);    
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
    $row_array[] = $row['EfficiencyRating'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Using the console log when this message is returned, how can I fix this?

> HP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in assets\configs\getdata.php on line 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

```
$res = odbc_exec($cnn, $sql);    
$return_arr = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
    $return_arr[] = $row['EfficiencyRating'];
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

*JS Part*

```
// Slightly modify the Request
$.post("assets/configs/getdata.php", {id:id}, function(data){
       // JSON Object
       console.log(data);

       $("input[name='rating']").val(data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: `$return_arr = array();` is not really required in this context ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the error has gone, it shows the value returned from the sql query in the console log now. How can I get it to output to the <input name="rating"></input>?

Comment: @Jez share your Returned Data

Comment: This is what the console log displays - ["89.4%"] This is what should be returned, except I want to show it in the Input field

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `$return_arr` before the `while` statement. Also, I personally feel what you are doing is just not right. The proper way would be this...

```
$res = odbc_exec($cnn, $sql);
$return_arr = array(); //<----------- Here    
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($return_arr,$row['EfficiencyRating']);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```